# How to view the table contents created by another user in oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have created a table 'T' under user 'SYS'. Now I want to view the contents of the same table 'T' under another user 'JACH'. I have granted the select privileges' on table 'T' to user 'JACH'. But when I try to view the table under 'JACH', it says table doesn't exist. How do I view the table data under user 'JACH'?[Logged in as user 'SYS']
[image: 1]
[Logged in as user 'JACH']
[image: 2]

Comment: Please do not create anything in user `SYS`

Comment: I tried creating under a different user and the results are the same. @MarmiteBomber

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to schema qualify your select statement.

If a table is created under **SCHEMA1** and you wish to query it while connected to **SCHEMA2**, assuming that **SCHEMA2** has been granted SELECT/READ privileges properly, you should be able to query the table while connected to **SCHEMA2** like this:

```sql
SELECT * FROM SCHEMA1.TABLE_NAME;
```